# Inverse logarithmic scale [0,0.9,0.99,0.999]

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to plot the equivalent of a [hdrhistogram](http://hdrhistogram.org), to analyse some latency data, however it seems non-trivial to do so since it requires what is essentially the inverse of a logarithmic scale.

I.e what I am trying to get is a scale that has ticks along the lines of: `[0,0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999]`

I'm coding this all via the Altair library for python, if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this in Altair, because it's not supported in Vega (see the two-year-old feature request here: https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1277)

But you can hack around it by transforming your data, using a standard log scale, and then computing new tick labels to reflect your underlying data. It might look something like this:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': range(5),
    'y': [0.0001, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999],
})

alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
  z = 1 - alt.datum.y  
).mark_line().encode(
  x='x:Q',
  y=alt.Y(
    'z:Q',
    scale=alt.Scale(type='log', reverse=True)),
    axis=alt.Axis(
      values=[1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001],
      labelExpr="1 - datum.value"),
)
```

[image]